# Files not found but exist

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have downloaded several files from ftp sites onto two different Windows 10 machines. After downloading them I attempt to back them up and do some further processing with commands including xcopy and move. The files are named some variation of name_timeDateStamp.csv. I use name_*.csv in the xcopy and move commands and no files are found. If I use n*.csv the files will be found. I've listed the filenames in hex to attempt to spot non-visible characters and nothing seems to be out of the ordinary. Does anyone have any thoughts on what may be causing this behavior?

files are named

```
move_data_20170823_2017082411074064.csv
move_data_20170823_2017082413303187.csv
move_data_20170824_2017082509534103.csv
move_data_20170824_2017082510490316.csv
```

```
dir m*.csv
```

finds them but

```
dir move_*.csv
```

does not.

Comment: Please give some examples of non-working filenames and the name you use to actually find the files. From your question, it sounds like you are using distinctly different file names.

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45945866/edit) and post what did you tried as code so far !

Comment: files are named move_data_20170823_2017082411074064.csv, move_data_20170823_2017082413303187.csv, move_data_20170824_2017082509534103.csv, move_data_20170824_2017082510490316.csv. "dir m*.csv" finds them but "dir move_*.csv" does not.

Comment: Hard to troubleshoot unless you show us all the code you are using. There could be something about what the current working directory is that you do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

A quick-and-dirty method of `move`ing the files is to use the short-filename; try

```
dir /X m*
```

Analysis of the precise reason for the failure of `dir move_*` would involve using a hex-editor on a directory-listing

```
dir m* >filename.txt
```

then use a hex-editor to view the names.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Short filenames didn't seem to make any difference.